# DateTime.hasvalue vs datetime == null, which one is better and why

Tags: c#, performance, datetime, null

i'd like to ask a question about **controlling null value** of a datetime.

```
if (mydatetime != null)
```

or

```
if(mydatetime.hasvalue)
```

which one is better, or proper and why?

thank you.

Comment: They are not exactly equivalent.  `HasValue` is only if the var is a Nullable

Comment: The first is true if it has a value, the second is true if it has no value. There is probably a `!` too much.

Comment: mine is nullable datetime (datetime? my datetime=null), in this case is there any difference?

Comment: @Aurora no difference, just be consistent

Answer (score 5):

The First comparison with `!=null` is a valid comparison, whereas the second can be used only if the variable is declared as Nullable, Or in other words comparison with `.HasValue` can only be used when the DateTime variable is declared as Nullable

For example :

```
DateTime dateInput; 
// Will set the value dynamically
if (dateInput != null)
{ 
   // Is a valid comparison         
}
if (dateInput.HasValue)
{ 
   // Is not a valid comparison this time        
}
```

Where as

```
DateTime? dateInput; // nullable declaration
// Will set the value dynamically
if (dateInput != null)
{ 
   // Is a valid comparison         
}
if (dateInput.HasValue)
{ 
   // Is also valid comparison this time        
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you ask

```
if (mydatetime != null)
```

you are checking whether the variable has been instantiated.

If it actually is **not** instantiated the following statement will give you
a `NullReferenceException`

```
if(!mydatetime.hasvalue)
```

because you are trying to access a property of an object that is `null`

Only if you declare the `DateTime` as `Nullable` will it display the same behaviour.

```
Nullable<DateTime> mydatetime = null;

Console.WriteLine(mydatetime.HasValue);
```